# Custom Styling in react-bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having some issues with custom styling in react-bootstrap.
More specifically, I am having some troubles styling the  component.
I am trying to center the contents of the Cards vertically.

I've created a custom.scss and linked it properly according to the react-bootstrap introduction page. The custom style loads into my HTML page... but is overriden by _transition.scss [overriden style here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvSHO.png)

I've also tried creating a "cardStyle" object in the component's file and then linking the style to the component with `style = "cardStyle"` - This seems to work okay... but some styles are still overriden.

I've also tried assigning the card a className, and then styling that className... gets overriden.

```
.card{
    background-color: aqua;
  }

.customCard{
  background-color: aqua;
}
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The only thing I was able to make work was adding !important to the styles in custom.scss
I feel like this is wrong and sloppy. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `background-color: aqua !important`. This overrides the style

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work with !important.

Is this the only way to override the default bootstrap CSS?